# Mac OS X - Objective C Runtime - What, Where, When?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

some general questions about the Mac OS X architecture.

I know roughly what the Objective C 2.0 Runtime does. (e.g. class loading, message dispatching, etc.)

However, I don't know where the runtime fits in the scheme of things, from the kernel up to individual processes.

- I believe it is a library, but what process is responsible for loading this library and running it?
- Is there one instance of the runtime operating at any one time on a system? Or several? (Is it per-process?)
- Is this architecture fundamentally the same (in terms of overall design) in iOS?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime code are all in `libobjc.A.dylib`. It works like a normal dynamic library, so it is loaded 1 time per process.

Comment: I have a question concerning your answer. I thought that if it is a dynamic library it is loaded into memory only once and then linked into every application at startup? I thought that static libraries are loaded every time for each process.

Comment: @Gorilla: Depends on what you mean by "load". By load I mean something like `dlopen`, where the code are mmaped into memory or reused, and the initialization routine is run, etc.

Comment: OK then we are talking about the same thing. So there is only one copy of the library in memory and is used by all the programs, whereas a static library could be in memory multiple times, one copy for each process which uses it.